# Query on mongodb using C#, I want to match BsonArray with BsonArray

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am doing a small project of CBIR (Content based images retrieval), I have calculated Histogram and Corner points, now I want to get results on the basis on matching histogram and corners, I have created index on histogram.

Where corners is list of dictionaries and histogram is `BsonArray`

I have tried just for histogram but it does not work

```
col.Find(Query.EQ("histogram", histogram)
```

One more thing if you can help I want to also get results those matches 90%.

Comment: you have misspelled "histogram" -- is that the problem?

Comment: yes you were that was my mistake, now I can get exact match of histogram, but the main problem is how I can get results if both histograms are partially same, (may be 90% same)